# If $(x_{n})$ is sequence with $x_{n} \leq b$ for all $n$, then $\text{lim}_{n \to \infty} x_{n} \leq b$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

> If $(x_{n})$ as sequence with $x_{n} \leq b$ for all $n$, then $\text{lim}_{n \to \infty} x_{n} \leq b $ if limit exists.

I see this fact being used very often and it seems fairly trivial but I am wondering how it can be proven rigorously.

**Proof attempt:**

Suppose that the limit exists.

Suppose $x_{n}\leq b$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then by definition of limit, for any arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, we can find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n^*>N$ we have $|(\text{lim}_{n \to \infty} x_{n})-x_{n^*}|< \epsilon$. Then $\text{lim}_{n \to \infty} x_{n}<\epsilon +x_{n^*} \leq \epsilon +b$

So $\text{lim}_{n \to \infty} x_{n}< \epsilon + b$ where $\epsilon$ is arbitrary.

This implies that at most, $\text{lim}_{n \to \infty} x_{n} \leq b$

Comment: "Assume $x_n$ is increasing and convergent without loss of generality" : how are you sure that you are not losing generality here?

Comment: Maybe it's not obvious if it's not monotonic but we can construct a monotonic subsequence which has the same limit. But in the case of decreasing limit, I think its pretty obvious?

Comment: You do not seem to have used the fact that it is increasing in the proof anyway. The proof is fine. Also, more is true : even if $x_n$ is not convergent, the limit superior  of $x_n$ is smaller than $b$.

Comment: I think I only needed to assume that the limit exists for my proof to work

Comment: Yes. In that  respect, this proof is fine. You proof is rigorous enough for my liking.

Comment: In fact, it's limsup bounded above by b.  Limsup always exists.

Comment: This is fine and a direct argument and +1 for that.  The proof via contradiction is more popular.

Comment: Treat b as a sequence and take limits.

Comment: Good proof. ..BTW $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=x$ is equivalent to: "For all $r>0$ the set $\{n\in \Bbb N: x_n\not \in (x-r,x+r)\}$ is finite." So if every $x_n\le b$ then for any $c>b$, consider $ r_c=(c-b)/2>0.$ Then the set $\{n\in \Bbb N: x_n\not \in (c-r_c,c+r_c)\}$ not only fails to be finite; it is all of $\Bbb N,$ so $\neg (\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=c).$